# Is it possible to create modal popup only from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an index.html that I cant edit. Only thing I can use is a javascript file that is linked to that index file. Modal is supposed to be created through javascript (through createElement method).

This is where I have a problem because I can't append that modal to document and I have a problem showing it directly from a function in the script.

Is this even possible to do in vanilla js? I know there are solutions with jquery but I am interested in the vanilla approach.

This is a test with a button so I would be sure it works, then I would code it to run on ready:

```
<button onclick="Popup()" role='button'>
    Show Alert
</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function Popup() {
        var myDialog = document.createElement("dialog");
        var text = document.createTextNode("This is a dialog window");
        myDialog.appendChild(text);
        myDialog.showModal();
    }
</script>
```

And here is the error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'showModal' on
>   'HTMLDialogElement': The element is not in a Document.

Comment: You will need to append the element `myDialog` to the document somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append the dialog element to the body using `document.body.appendChild(myDialog)`

```js
function Popup() {
  var myDialog = document.createElement("dialog");
  document.body.appendChild(myDialog)
  var text = document.createTextNode("This is a dialog window");
  myDialog.appendChild(text);
  myDialog.showModal();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Popup()" role='button'>
    Show Alert
</button>
```

Comment: This is a good solution - never heard of this tag before. Be careful of the [limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=dialog), though.

Comment: @esqew won't it work if we use some other HTML element like div ??

Comment: @esqew `dialog` is a new tag introduced as part of html5.2.
https://bitsofco.de/whats-new-in-html-5-2/?utm_source=frontendfocus&utm_medium=email

Comment: It works. It probably works with every element type. My mistake was not trying to append it to body. I just tried to append it to document.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no "dialog" element that has that functionality. You'll have to create a regular element append it to the document and then have css to position it.